# How can I refresh the script on each new candle?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I have this script to make the current, unclosed bar transparent

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
i_transp = 80

barcolor(barstate.islast ? close > open ? color.new(color.teal, i_transp) : color.new(color.red, i_transp) : na)
```

The problem is the candle stays transparent even when a new one appears, until I refresh the page.
Can I do this automatically with pine script? Or is there a way to change any closed candles to solid colour?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why `barstate.islast` is not working in this example (as well as `barstate.isrealtime`, `barstate.ishistory` - all combination of those have the same issue).

But I found the way to achieve your goal by using `barstate.isconfirmed`:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
i_transp = 80

var color c_teal = color.new(color.teal, i_transp)
var color c_red = color.new(color.red, i_transp)

color c_barcolor = close > open ? c_teal : c_red

barcolor(not barstate.isconfirmed ? c_barcolor : na)

// or
// barcolor(barstate.isconfirmed ? na : c_barcolor)
```